# What is direction of many to many bidirectional?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a "many to many" bidirectional, but when I create mapping data for Group and User, it's only working with 1 direction.

```py
class Groups(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'GROUPS'
    grpid = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    groups = db.relationship("GroupUsers", back_populates="profiles")

class Profiles(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'PROFILES'
    profileid = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    profiles = db.relationship("GroupUsers", back_populates="groups")

class GroupUsers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'GRPUSERS'
    autoid = db.Column(db.String)
    brid = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    grpid = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("GROUPS.grpid"), primary_key=True)
    profileid = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("PROFILES.tlid"), primary_key=True)

    groups = db.relationship("Groups", back_populates="profiles")
    profiles = db.relationship("Profiles", back_populates="groups")

# CREATE MAPPING
groups = Groups()
group = groups.get_by_grpid(grpid=grid)
profiles = Profiles()
profile = profiles.get_by_profileid(profileid=profileid)
groupuser = GroupUsers(autoid=GroupUsers.get_max_autoid(),brid=profile.brid)

# IT'S WORK. CAN CREATE PRIMARY KEY TO GRPUSERS
# groupuser.tlprofiles = profile
# group.profiles.append(groupuser)
# profile.save()

# IT ISN'T WORK WITH ERROR BELOW
groupuser.tlgroups = group
profile.groups.append(groupuser)
group.save()
```

When I create mapping from profile, it add primary key to `GroupUser` class, but when I create mapping from group, it can not create primary key for `GroupUser` class with error.

```
Can't update table GRPUSERS using NULL for primary key value on column GRPUSERS.profileid
```